# sailsjs one-way associations confusion

Tags: sails.js, associations

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around associations with sailsjs.

I have 2 models

Services

```
attributes: {
    status: {
        defaultsTo: 'inactive'
    },
    userId:{
        model: 'users',
        via: 'id',
      },

},
```

Users

```
  attributes: {
    email: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: 'string'
    }

  },
```

So, a service is tied to a user (matching the id of the user).

I used to do a call like http://localhost:1337/Services?userId=**userId**

Now I would like to transition to associations using the above model attributes.

This works by calling the ID of the service just fine (it includes the users data as well), however if all i have is the user, how could I get the service

Doing the same call (http://localhost:1337/Services?userId=**userId**) returns and empty object.

Am I forced to actually have a one-to-one or one-to-many association? I don't understand why I can no longer use the userId field (stored in the DB) to do queries once I start using associations. I guess I am looking for the best of both worlds here.

EDIT:

Let me try make this more clear. Before trying to do associations, I could call this URL (using blueprint)

```
http://localhost:1337/Services?userId=userId
```

The Services model used to look like this

```
attributes: {
status: {
    defaultsTo: 'inactive'
},
userId:{
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  },

  },
```

Then when a user is created, a service for that user is created with the userId matching the ID in the Users table.

Now I would like to implement associations using the above model scheme.

However, because (my best guess) the **userId** field of the service is mapped to the Users model, I am unable to search for a Server using the **userId** field that is stored.

I hope that makes sense? In another words, tryin to call

```
http://localhost:1337/Services?userId=userId
```

returns nothing when using associations but does return a value when I don't use associations

Comment: Your explanation is a little vague. For one and the same call you are stating: 1. The call used to work. 2. Now it returns an empty object. I see two models and I don't know what was the state of your app when things were working and what is the state when they don't work. What did you change? And how do you want them to work - by using blueprints or not? Cause I don't use blueprints - they are mostly for prototyping and considered dangerous for production.

Comment: What @logout said but also, your definition in the Services model: `model: 'clients'` You have not provided the clients model, should not this not be `users` instead of `clients`?

Comment: @CraigvanTonder thanks, I updated the post.

Comment: So each user can have one service and a service can belong to only one user? Battling to understand what you're trying to achieve here as a whole but will take a look a bit later and see how if I can help. Also what version of sails are you using?

Comment: For now yes. As time goes on, a user may have multiple services (i.e. a service may belong to 1 user only, however there may be many services bound to a user). I am using sails 0.12.11